# Remove the side border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have menu like the described in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzzq93qy/)
It's a right to left menu.

If you can see the left border when mouse hover still active. I want when mouse hover to remove the left side border

CSS

```
nav ul li:hover{
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:FAC3BC;
    border-top: 15px;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: There's a couple things, your containing element has a border, so the left border of the left-most item will not have an effect on that, and the left border you're seeing is actually the right border of the preceding`li`

Comment: here a jquery solution if u want http://jsfiddle.net/j8r7v39L/1/  ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've found a solution, if I understand what you mean.

[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frippa/rzzq93qy/3/)

I've added this line:

```
nav ul li:hover + li{
    border-right:none;
}
```

OR

```
border-right:1px solid transparent;
```